# В чем ошибка? Добавляю контролер с представлениями

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mvc

При попытке создать контроллер с представлениями
[image: Скриншот]

Получаю ошибку

[image: Скриншот]

Содержание файлов:

**1) web.config**

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="data source=ms-sql-8.in-solve.ru;initial catalog=1gb_dobsh1; user id=****;password=****;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

**2) Модель Working**

```
[Key]
[Column(Order = 0)]
[Required]
[Display(Name = "Пользователь")]
string UserId { get; set; }

[Key]
[Column(Order = 1)]//Дата простановки
[ScaffoldColumn(false)]
DateTime Date { get; set; }

//НЕ ОТРАБОТКА!
[Display(Name = "Начало года отработки. Пример уч. год 15/16 - год отработки 15")]
int YearWork { get; set; }

[Display(Name = "Кол-во часов")]
int Hours { get; set; }
```

**3) Контекст**

```
public MyContext() : base("DefaultConnection") { }
public DbSet<Working> Working { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я так понимаю, класс модели у Вас называется `Working`. В этом случае поле айди должно называться либо `Id` либо `WorkingId`. Если Вы хотите задать собственное название, добавьте в контекст следующее:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Working>.HasKey(x => x.UserId);
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```